# Javascript & Jquery defining a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to define a global jquery object variable so that I can access it from different functions.

This is what I am doing:

```
var object_list = $("#object_list");
var list_length = object_list.find("li").length;

$(document).on('keydown', '#object_list', function(event) {
    //both of these don't work
    alert(object_list);
    alert(list_length);
});
```

Well,, for some reason this is not working (the first alert gives me NULL and the second gives me 0, which is not).

Why aren't my global variables working..??

Thanks!!

Comment: `#object__list` and `#object_list`? Hmmmmm

Comment: And you wrapped that in document ready or inserted the script after the elements.

Comment: Also note that `object_list` would equal `this` inside the event handler, so it doesn't make much sense ?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a scope issue - there's a typo in your code:

```
var object_list = $("#object__list"); // 2 underscores

$(document).on('keydown', '#object_list', function(event) { // 1 underscore
```

So long as `object_list` and `list_length` are declared in a parent function this should work.

Alternatively, you could attach the variables to the `window` object, so they can be used anywhere at all in your code:

```
window.object_list = $("#object__list");
window.list_length = object_list.find("li").length;
```

As stated though, this should not be necessary given your code in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo,,, but it was just my mistake copying the code... The typo doesn't exist in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var object_list;
var list_length;

$(document).ready(function() {
    object_list = $("#object__list");
    list_length = object_list.find("li").length;
});

$(document).on('keydown', '#object_list', function(event) {
    alert(object_list);
    alert(list_length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're delegating event handling to `document`, and I assume that's because that `#object_list` does not exist in the page at the moment you bind the event. If it also doesn't exist at the moment you define `object_list` and `list_length`, that's why they're empty. And once empty, they won't be populated automatically when the elements are added.
Try this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#object_list', function(event) {
    alert(this);
    alert($(this).find('li').length);
});
```